# How to check if a file exists without also checking if I got the permission to read it?

Tags: .net

File.Exists and FileInfo.Exists can't be used in this case, as they check if the file exists AND the permission levels are sufficient.

Is there an easy way to check if a file exists regardless of the permissions?

The context of the problem is a common one: asking the user if they really want to overwrite an existing file. You seldom want to overwrite a file you don't own, and a call to File.Exists would miss that case and confuse it with the file not existing.

Comment: If you don't have access rights to a particular directory a cant see how you would be able to check if files exists there or not. But you can probably check if you have [access or not](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Csharp/30271754/check-users-directory-permissions.aspx)

Comment: Magnus: Right, but I was thinking of the case where you have the rights to the directory, but not to a file in it.

Comment: It seems the MSDN documentation for File.Exists is wrong. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx says "If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.". I just tested on Windows 7 pro and File.Exists returns true for a file for which I have denied myself read rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static bool FileExists(string path)
{
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    string file = Path.GetFileName(path);
    bool exists = (dirInfo.Exists && dirInfo.EnumerateFiles().Any(f => f.Name == file));
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but couldn't one use `path` as the argument to `EnumerateFiles()` instead of using `Any()`? Might be faster to let the OS do the search than do it in a .Net process, especially for directories with lots of files. Maybe one should also catch `SecurityException`, which If I understood it correctly is thrown when the process lacks the rights to list the content of the directory. Finally MSDN says the static `Directory` class is faster if one is not interested in any info about the file but its name.

Comment: @Joh Catching exceptions should be done higher up in the call stack not in this method.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work using DirectoryInfo?

```
DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo("your_directory_path");
FileInfo[] listfiles = root.GetFiles("*");
if (listfiles.Length > 0)
{
  //File exists
  foreach (FileInfo file in listfiles)
  {
      //
  }
}
else
{
 //
}
```

Comment: Some possible improvements: Check if the directory exists, otherwise the code may throw a `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Use `EnumerateFiles()` instead of `GetFiles()`, for performance reasons. Maybe using the name of the file as the pattern in `GetFiles`/`EnumerateFiles` could provide better performance. I don't think you need an `if (length > 0)`, `foreach` simply won't do anything if the directory is empty.